# Pass a value to a PHP page using a custom httpmodule

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, adfs

I have a PHP page running on IIS8.
Authentication is done through ADFS.
I would like to access the values of some of the claims in the user's SAML token from the PHP page, but I think those values are not stored anyway.
I tried creating a custom HttpModule to pass values to the PHP page:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;

public class TestModule : IHttpModule {

    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
        context.AuthenticateRequest += Context_AuthenticateRequest;
    }

    private void Context_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        IClaimsPrincipal principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as IClaimsPrincipal;
        if (principal == null || principal.Identities == null || principal.Identities.Count == 0) {
            context.Response.Write("TestModule: cannot get claims.<br/>");
            return;
        } 
        IClaimsIdentity identity = principal.Identities[0];
        foreach (Claim claim in identity.Claims) {
            if (claim.ClaimType == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/DisplayName") {
                context.Response.Write("TestModule: setting USER_DISPLAY_NAME to " + claim.Value + "<br/>");
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("USER_DISPLAY_NAME", claim.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
    }

}
```

This is executed, and the variable is set to the good value.
In the PHP page I have this:

```
<?php
echo getenv('USER_DISPLAY_NAME');
?>
```

But nothing is displayed.

Is it possible to pass a variable to a PHP page with a custom module?

Is there another more standard way to get ADFS claims values from a PHP page in IIS?

Comment: I think using `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` with only 2 parameters only affects the current app.  Maybe https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes(v=vs.110).aspx is helpful.

Comment: Infact, I would like to affect only the current request. I'm using env vars because I couldn't find anything better...

Comment: Only way I can think of is invoking the PHP script with the claim as a post parameter and waiting for the response (if you need to), before closing the current request. Otherwise you could see if you could find some sort of session sharing mechanism (e.g. store the session in a shared memory cache like Redis).